# not in for dict() does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code. I only want to record the value in dictionary named "country" when  key,value does not exist in dictionary. For this purpose i am checking keyword not in(second last line of code). However, it does not work. it updates the value even the key exist in the dictionary. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
country = dict()

for file in allFiles:

   df = pd.read_excel(file,'Internal', skiprows = 7)
   print ("file name is " + file)

   if(df.loc[1][0] ==  "Country:"):
      key = df.loc[1][1]
      value = df.loc[2][1]
   else:
      key = df.loc[2][1]
      value = df.loc[1][1]

   print ('key is ' , key)
   print ('value is ' , value)

   try:
       print (df.loc[47][2], df.loc[47][3])
       print (df.loc[49][2], df.loc[49][3])

   except Exception as inst:
       print (type(inst))
       print (inst.args)
       print (inst)


   if ((key not in country) or (value != 'nan')):
      country[key] = value
```

Comment: Read the condition on your if statement, and think of what will happen if `value` is not nan.

Answer (score 4):

Change your condition from

```
# Even if 'key' was already in 'country', If (value != 'nan')
# evaluated to 'True', the update will happen
if ((key not in country) or (value != 'nan')):
```

to

```
# Do not update unless 1- the key does not exist AND 2- value is not 'nan'
if (key not in country) and (value != 'nan'):
```

Since `value` is (most likely) not `nan`, the record will always be updated.